# $lookup aggregation failed to display array value

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I'm working with MongoDB and I've 2 collections.

**data collection ["user-profile"]**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60650e6fc4b4603e1e78bb23"), 
    "firstName" : "Luthfan", 
    "lastName" : "Difiesa", 
    "mobile" : "86742633497", 
    "gender" : "male",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2021-04-22T05:26:07.428+0000"), 
    "updatedOn" : ISODate("2021-04-22T05:26:55.218+0000")
}
```

**data collection ["user-wishlist"]**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60650e7a1a4a817a1dd0a29c"), 
    "userId" : "86742633497", 
    "contents" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ef9d2da228f840bbd41649c"), 
            "name" : "Kelas 11"
        }
    ]
}
```

**expected output:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60650e6fc4b4603e1e78bb23"), 
    "firstName" : "Luthfan", 
    "lastName" : "Difiesa", 
    "mobile" : "86742633497", 
    "gender" : "male",
    "contents" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ef9d2da228f840bbd41649c"), 
            "name" : "Kelas 11"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Here's the query:**

```
db.getCollection("user-profile").aggregate(
    [ 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "user-wishlist", 
                "localField" : "mobile", 
                "foreignField" : "userId", 
                "as" : "contents"
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

**But the result is like this:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60650e6fc4b4603e1e78bb23"), 
    "firstName" : "Luthfan", 
    "lastName" : "Difiesa", 
    "mobile" : "86742633497", 
    "gender" : "male",
    "contents" : [

    ]
}
```

is't because of collection name using special character or type data from foreign or localField? thank u...

Comment: query looks good, it should work, please verify collection name `user-wishlist` in databse.

Comment: That query works in the playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/olilI_wUMkH

Comment: i've updated the collection name and add 2 column (createdOn and updateOn). when i try it in playgroud [link] (https://mongoplayground.net/p/BleBiWWI8Lt) i got error cannot parse date @turivishal

Comment: check localField and foreignField are of the same data type

Comment: both of them are string @Beingnin

Comment: @yunanhelmi It is just timezone issue in both dates see corrected [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u61KpPymZzP)

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks good, just need add a stage after lookup to achieve your desire result,

```
{
  $addFields: {
    contents: {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$contents.contents", 0]
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BhdUXZQtlkz)

Comment: I was expecting a flaw in your code thinking that `$arrayElemAt` returns only the first item from the `contents` array even if it has more than 1 item. Surprisingly it is not. It is returning all items inside the contents array. Im confused

Comment: compare the result with $addFields stage and without $addFields stage, the `user-wishlist` collection have key `contents` and as per Question expected result he wants to show only that field in result.

Comment: I did understand why u have added the `$addFields` stage. But what confusing me is I was expecting the `arrayElemAt` operator to return only the first item from the `$contents.contents` array since you have clearly mentioned 0 as the index. But when I tried it in playground with multiple items in contents array, it is still returning all the items . https://mongoplayground.net/p/JxXKQ74LuWj

Comment: the `contents.contents` its nested array so this will return 2 level nested array `[[]]` so we have selected element from first element. just check for your clarification add new stage after lookup stage `{ $addFields: { contents: "$contents.contents" } }`.

Comment: I think I understood now. It is not taking the first item from `$contents.contents` array like I thought. Instead it is taking the `contents` field(which is an array) of the first item from `contents` array

Comment: @turvishal: I wasn't the one who asked this qn. BTW I think the OP's problem wasnt the structure of the desired result but the issue he\she facing with `$lookup`

Comment: @Beingnin ahh really sorry, i did not recognise that you are not OP.